# Best performance for string-to-Boolean conversion

Tags: java

Which of the below options has the best performance while converting string to Boolean?

1. `boolean value = new Boolean("true").booleanValue();`
2. `boolean value = Boolean.valueOf("true");`
3. `boolean value = Boolean.parseBoolean("true");`

Comment: 1. Try benchmarking. 2. I'd almost bet precious parts of my anatomy that casting a String to a boolean value is **not** the performance bottleneck of whatever application you're working on.

Comment: (The answer is almost certainly 3, but you should really have experimented first.)

Comment: This is a legitimate question. It's difficult to benchmark correctly in Java. I think it's reasonable that the poster didn't attempt to.

Comment: How would it be difficult to benchmark this? Just do each of 1, 2, and 3, say, 1 million times, and compare the distribution of timings.

Comment: @JackManey: it's difficult due to JIT, method inlining, virtual calls optimization, unpredictable GC pauses...

Comment: @JackManey See Brian Goetz's article on microbenchmarking http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp02225/index.html

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
boolean value = new Boolean("true").booleanValue();
```

is the worst. It creates new `Boolean` objects all the time. BTW, `booleanValue()` is not necessary; unboxing will do it for you.

```
boolean value = Boolean.valueOf("true");
```

is much better. It uses a cached `Boolean` instance, but it performs unnecessary (although very cheap) unboxing.

```
boolean value = Boolean.parseBoolean("true");
```

is best. Nothing is wasted, it operates barely on primitives, and no memory allocations are involved. BTW, all of them delegate to (Sun/Oracle):

```
private static boolean toBoolean(String name) { 
  return ((name != null) && name.equalsIgnoreCase("true"));
}
```

If you are paranoid, you can create your own `toBoolean(String name)` not ignoring case— it is negligibly faster:

```
boolean value = "true".equals(yourString);
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is the source:

```
public static Boolean valueOf(String s) {
    return toBoolean(s) ? TRUE : FALSE;
}

public static boolean parseBoolean(String s) {
    return toBoolean(s);
}

public Boolean(String s) {
    this(toBoolean(s));
}

private static boolean toBoolean(String name) {
    return ((name != null) && name.equalsIgnoreCase("true"));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The second and third one are the best options since they are **static factory methods** and internally they can reuse references.

Looking at the `Boolean.valueOf("true")` and `Boolean.parseBoolean("true")` implementations, they both do the same (they both call `toBoolean(s);`) with the difference that `valueOf` returns the Boxed type.