# Performance Boolean.ValueOf vs new Boolean(request.getParameter("value"))

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best performance for string to boolean conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12044721/best-performance-for-string-to-boolean-conversion)

Which is considered better practice and more importantly will one give me better performance?

Comment: There only two possible Boolean objects so you should never need to create another one.  Ideally you should use `boolean` instead of `Boolean` where possible as this clearer IMHO and will be 4x smaller (or better)

Answer (score 10):

The documentation for the Boolean constructor says:

```
 * <p><b>Note: It is rarely appropriate to use this constructor.
 * Unless a <i>new</i> instance is required, the static factory
 * {@link #valueOf(boolean)} is generally a better choice. It is
 * likely to yield significantly better space and time performance.</b>
```

`valueOf` returns a reference to a constant value so that no new object is created.

Comment: Given the title contains `new Boolean(request.getParameter("value"))`, I think he is talking about `Boolean.valueOf(String)`, so the javadoc in question is not a really relevant answer as it refers to `Boolean.valueOf(boolean)`.

Comment: @Mark: i think it's relevant, he has to read the string in and do a comparison in any event, the only difference is whether there's a constructor call. (both ways end up calling toBoolean.)